# Probability of one person with $2$ different bank cards with last same $3$ digits?

Tags: probability

There are similar questions on here, but I am a novice and do not truly understand most of the answers.  My question actually concerns the last $4$ numbers on a bank card, the ones we often use as identifier for security questions.
For example, what are the chances ONE person would have a debit card from one bank with the last $4$ numbers of say, $0267$, and a diff banks credit card with last $4$ numbers of say, $1267$? Do you just calculate the one diff digit having $9$ different chances of being same number, or wouldn't you calculate all $4$ having the same amount of chances at being different? I am confusing myself! In similar questions on this site, it appears the answer would be $10^4$?  And how would that be phrased?
"That person has a one in a --?-- chance of that happening." Thank you all for your patience - I have no experience with this, just curiosity!

Comment: Do you want that **only** the last $3$ digits match, or are the last $4$ digits allowed to match ?

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that the last four digits are evenly distributed then the probability of the last three matching is simply $1$ in $1000$.  So, the question is whether they are evenly distributed.  Answering that precisely would require a lot of knowledge of the banking system.  In the absence of this knowledge, and any evidence to the contrary, it is a reasonable assumption.  One person's random might be another's predictable.  If I called out the digits $7, 1, 8, 2, 8, 1, 8, 2, 8, 4, 5, 9, 0, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5, 3, 6$  Many might think that they are random but some would guess the next five would be $0, 2, 8, 7, 4$

The answer would probably be different if you asked about the first three digits.  I think that the first four identify the issuer and these are probably not evenly distributed.  Many are probably not used at all, others will be very common (large banks), and some will occur but rarely (small banks).

Again, I think that the last digit is a checksum and hence calculated from the previous ones.  So, what is the probability of all 16 digits matching when a card is drawn randomly twice with replacement?  A naive answer is $1$ in $10^{16}$ since there are 16 digits.  My checksum comment drops this to $1$ in $10^{15}$.  My comment on the first four drops it again.  Of course, the actual answer should be $1$ in *number-of-cards-in-circulation*.  If you draw two cards without replacement then the probability should be $0$ but there is some danger of cloned cards so maybe not.

Back to your question.  If we trust that the checksum algorithm is good and that the banks arbitrarily assign the last few digits then the answer of $1$ in $1000$ is reasonable.  If the checksum algorithm was very poor and only depended on the previous two digits then the answer would be only $1$ in $100$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all bank numbers are valid, then there is indeed a $1$ in $10^3$ chance of the event happening. We can see that the last three digits of the second credit card number has $10^3$ total different combinations, and only one of them  could ever correlate with the last three digits of the first credit card number.